# Discord.py Как получить Id канала через упоминания

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-api

Как получить Id канала через упоминания

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

В следующий раз, пожалуйста, постарайтесь конкретизировать Ваш вопрос.

Вот как я понял Вашу задачу: Вам необходимо получить `ID` канала из упоминания при использовании команды (`.команда #канал`). 
Вот решение:

```
@bot.command()
async def command(ctx, channel:discord.Channel):
    await ctx.send(f'ID канала: {channel.id}')
```